# Cassandra counter datatype operation in spring repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring-boot application in which I want to create Cassandra **counter** tables if not exist. I am using the repository for the same.

**UserPoints POJO:**

```
/**
 * 
 * @author Prakash Pandey 23-Nov-2017
 *
 */
@Table("user_points")
public class UserPoints {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "app_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private long appId;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "user_name", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private String userName;

    @Column(value = "points")
    long points;


    public long getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(long appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public long getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(long points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPoints [appId=" + appId + ", userName=" + userName + ", points=" + points + "]";
    }
}
```

**UserPointRepository POJO:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserPointRepository extends CassandraRepository<UserPoints> {

}
```

The table was created successfully in Cassandra database with the below definition :

```
CREATE TABLE user_points (
  app_id bigint,
  user_name text,
  points bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (app_id, user_name)
)
```

**The problem** is that data type of `points` column is `bigint`, expected is `counter` data-type.

**I have two questions**:

1. How to create a counter(column having counter
   datatype) table using the repository.
2. How to update (increment, decrement) a counter column using the
   repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL; DR.

`counter`s are not supported through repositories, and I'm not sure there is a good way to support them.

### Explanation

Spring Data Repositories are designed to save/update an entity with the data from the actual object passed to `save(Object)`. No database-side modifiers are applied. A counter requires server-side operations (increment, decrement) which can't be expressed through a `save(…)` method.

Comment: Incrementing counter using repository works fine.

`@Query("update user_points_date set points = points + 1 where app_id=?0 and date=?1 and user_name=?2")
 public void incrementUserPoints(long appId, String date, String userName, int counter);`

The problem is only while creating counter tables using auto table creating in spring

Comment: Adding `@CassandraType(type=COUNTER)` should help.

Comment: Where to add `@CassandraType(type=COUNTER)`. Do you mean above column that represent counter column and also what should be the data type to that column int, Long, Integer or what

Comment: Yes, the field mapped to the counter column. Check out the type mapping for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-conversion